# How to delegate selected item on alertDialog with translation

Tags: java, android, string

i don't understand how to translate strings inside alertDialog with array.xml and delegate selected item.

i have this code to show my alertdialog:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {
                        "Spam",
                        "Nudez ou pornografia",
                        "Violência explícita",
                        "Ataque a um grupo ou indivíduo",
                        "Outro"
                };

                final String REASON_SPAM = "REASON_SPAM";
                final String REASON_NUDITY = "REASON_NUDITY";
                final String REASON_VIOLENCE = "REASON_VIOLENCE";
                final String REASON_BULLYING = "REASON_BULLYING";
                final String REASON_OTHERS = "REASON_OTHERS";

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                builder.setTitle("Motivo");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        String reason = REASON_OTHERS;
                        if (items[item].equals("Spam")) {
                            reason = REASON_SPAM;
                        } else if (items[item].equals("Nudez ou pornografia")) {
                            reason = REASON_NUDITY;
                        } else if (items[item].equals("Violência explícita")) {
                            reason = REASON_VIOLENCE;
                        } else if (items[item].equals("Ataque a um grupo ou indivíduo")) {
                            reason = REASON_BULLYING;
                        } else {
                            reason = REASON_OTHERS;
                        }

                        ProfileTask.reportUser(ctx, userEntity.apiId, reason);
                    }
                }).show();
            }
```

i need to translate strings :|

Comment: You have to use localized String ressources as described in [android-application-localization-tutorial](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/)

Comment: I understand the localized strings, but did not want to leave the hardcoded strings in my if statement.

Comment: With "localized String ressources" i mean that you have to replace every hardcoded strings with resources. i.e. <pre>"Spam"</pre> will become <pre>getString(R.string.spam)</pre>

Comment: but that is precisely what I dont want to do, is ugly; Love it if there was a way to use the values-xx /arrays.xml and delegate selected item, somehow that way I do not need to leave coded all the possibilities in my if statement